# Get nodes from XML file where name has "."

Tags: r, xml

I have a XML file of the following type

```
<timeseries><mrid>1</mrid><businesstype>A96</businesstype><flowdirection.direction>A02</flowdirection.direction><quantity_measure_unit.name>MAW</quantity_measure_unit.name>
```

and I use the following code and it shows output `{xml_nodeset (0)}`. but when I try to search for "businesstype" then I have the results from the node. I think the problem is in "." inside the node name. How can be the problem solved using the same function as in my code?

```
library(rvest)
xml %>% html_elements("flowdirection.direction") %>% html_text()
xml %>% html_nodes("flowdirection.direction")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default selector type for `html_elements` (and `html_nodes()`) is a CSS selector. In CSS selectors the `.` has a special meaning to indicate the HTML "class" of a node. If you want to use CSS selectors, you have to escape the `.` with a backslash. For example

```
xml <- xml2::read_xml("<timeseries><mrid>1</mrid><businesstype>A96</businesstype><flowdirection.direction>A02</flowdirection.direction>

xml %>%  
  html_elements("flowdirection\\.direction")
```

or you could use `xpath` selectors

```
xml %>%  
  html_elements(xpath="flowdirection.direction")
```

This might make more sense because you seem to be working with raw XML data rather than HTML nodes.